# TFS - How to branch again?

Tags: tfs, branch

I have a large project which I branched to make some changes to the branch. Now I worked on the branch for a while and never branched back to the main. Then I switched back to the main and continued to add more features to the main. Now I need to work again on the previous branch, however I think I need to first update the branch with the changes that I made to the main. How can I do that? Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the file in the main branch -> Merge -> choose the branch you want to merge to.

Comment: Right click on a file, folder or the entire project -> view history.
There you'll be able to see all the changesets.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it sounds like you don't want to "branch" again, you want to **merge**.  First, make sure you have a workspace mapped that contains both the trunk and the branch.  Then, right click on the trunk (main) and choose "merge"-- if you're using TFS 2010, this will be under Branching/Merging on the right click.

Make sure your destination is correct, and, in this case it sounds like you can merge all files up until current.  This will merge all changes in the main trunk with the changes you have in your branch.  Once the merge operation is done, and you have resolved any/all conflicts, check in the changes on the branch.